# SQL - Create table with one column that has date by week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'd like to create a table that has one column and the column is weekly dates starting with 1/1/2015 thru the end of 2015.  Is there an easy way to do this?

ie

```
CREATE TABLE Week_End_Dates
(
WeekEndDt date
);

INSERT INTO Week_End_Dates(WeekEndDt)
VALUES ('2015-01-01'),('2015-01-08')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to generate a date sequence. One is to use a common table expression like this:

```
WITH CTE (DT) AS 
(
    SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE) DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DT)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DT) < '2016-01-01'
)
INSERT INTO Week_End_Dates(WeekEndDt)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

It's not the most efficient (and can easily be optimized in several ways), but it should do what you seem to want.

The query would generate a result like:

```
WeekEndDt
2015-01-01
2015-01-08
2015-01-15
2015-01-22
2015-01-29
... etc until 2015-12-31
```